# Regular expression to match only if there are N unique characters

Tags: .net, regex

Is there a way how to define regular expression in which will match only if there are at least N unique characters?

Example: (N = 3)

```
aba  => no match  
abc  => match
abbc => match
ab   => no match
abcd => match
```

Comment: This is not a RegEx job, but more like Map-Reduce job.

Comment: There is used .NET on the project (C#)

Comment: You can achieve it but it will be horribly slow. You really don't want to do this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really, this is not a regex problem.

A much easier solution would be to use a Set like [HashSet(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)

1. Split the string to characters and add each one to the set.
2. Count the number of elements in the set.

Comment: I think this is a good approach but be careful with step 1. If the strings are user generated then there's potential to descend into unicode hell. E.G. should ë and e be consider the same character? Should  ß be considered as ss? There are lots of potential problems with splitting strings into 'characters'.

Comment: True but do any of those problems not apply to using regex on user generated strings?

Answer (score 2):

These problems are pretty tricky to do using `regex`.

SInce question is tagged as **`regex`** you can try this `lookahead` based regex:

```
(.).*?((?!.*?\1).).*?((?!.*?\2).)
```

- First this matches any character and captures that in group #1
- Then it searches in the string any character which is not group #1 and captures that in group #2
- Finally it further searches in the string any character which is not group #2

**Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/dH1rP4**

It **doesn't match:**

1. aba
2. adaaaaaa
3. aaaabbbb

It **matches:**

1. abc
2. adaac
3. abbc
4. adaaac
5. 11112222220

Comment: This test fails: `/(.)((?!.*?\1).)((?!.*?\2).)/.test('adaaac')` even though it has three unique characters in it.

Comment: @mybrave: See updated demo with your updated examples: http://regex101.com/r/aZ4aF1

Comment: This one looks promising! but agree it is not common task for regular expression as written in other answer.

Comment: Yes sure I just took that as a puzzle and created this regex which came off pretty well.

Comment: Well done but I don't understand why this doesn't match aba. A is the first group, b is different to a and then a is different to b. This seems to check the third group against both 1 and 2 but your description and my understanding say it shouldn't be.

Comment: OK I will test this with your input and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

```
/(?:(.)(?!.*?\1).*){3}/
```

Change 3 with the desired value of unique characters

PREEDIT - Just for documentation and to keep coherence for the comments, this was the original answer posted

```
/^(?:(.)(?!.*\1.*$)){3}$/
```

No, it does not what the OP needed, i misunderstood the problem. This regexp tests that the string is formed **only** by the indicated number of unique characters.

Comment: @sudo_O: Are you sure? Not tested on c# (in this moment i can use it) but in javascript it works.

Comment: e.g. it fails for `abbc`

Comment: @anubhava: no , it does not fail. There is no 3 unique characters, only unique characters are `a` and `c`

Comment: I seems to match `aba` http://rubular.com/r/vgEMR0caLt that is the first and last character can repeat when `n=3` after some testing it only check that adjacent letters don't repeat.

Comment: @MCND: See this demo: http://regex101.com/r/zM1qH5 matched both `aba` (invalid), `abc` (valid) but failed to match `abbc` which is also valid.

Comment: @anubhava: have not think of `aba`, i will see, but for me, `abbc` is invalid as there is no 3 unique characters, only two, 'a' and 'c', b is duplicated.

Comment: sorry, added few more examples to make it clear what I wanted to achieve

Comment: @anubhava: please, is there any case i have not taken in consideration?

Comment: @MCND: This new regex definitely looks better, I haven't got a chance to test it (will test it as soon as I get back to my computer).